# Ideals of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_n[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

The initial question was to find how many ideals are in the ring  $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$.

My first answer was that they're infinite many since we can take $\langle x^n+1\rangle , n>1$,

but in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X] \;x=x^2=x^3=...$

So we end up with $4$ ideals in the end ? $\langle 0\rangle,\langle1\rangle,\langle x\rangle,\langle x+1\rangle$?

I am a bit confused about what's the correct answer, could someone help me clarify this.

*More generally, in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_n[X]$, do we have an upper bound on the cardinality of the ideals, or are there infinitely many of them?*

Comment: $x$ and $x^2$ are equal as functions, but unequal as polynomials, which is what counts here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So the ideals are infinite, thanks.